# XAMPP - MYSQL Shutdown Unexpectedly 2

Tags: mysql, xampp

I tried to launch MySql on xampp and this error appeared

```
16:11:30  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
16:11:30  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
16:11:33  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
16:11:33  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
16:11:33  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
16:11:33  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
16:11:33  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
16:11:33  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
16:11:33  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
16:11:33  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums





2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 2590483; transaction id 4333
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-05-31 16:11:30 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

It was completely fine until now.

What is this error and how do i fix it?